# Microsoft SQL Server : SUM and LEFT JOIN double values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get data from an contability software that is using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I am trying to get the total of money and to get a field called Numero de Obra (number of work) from an invoice in one line, the problem is a need to sum some items to get the total, and when i get the extra field number of work my data is getting duplicated.

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    GVA12.FECHA_EMIS AS [Fecha de emisión] ,
    GVA53.T_Comp AS [Tipo comprobante] ,
    GVA53.N_Comp AS [Nro. comprobante] ,
    GVA12.COD_VENDED AS [Cód. vendedor] ,
    CASE GVA12.COD_VENDED WHEN '**' THEN 'CONTADO' ELSE GVA23.NOMBRE_VEN END AS [Nombre Vendedor] ,
    GVA12.COD_CLIENT AS [Cód. cliente] ,
    CASE GVA12.COD_CLIENT WHEN '000000' THEN 'OCASIONAL' ELSE GVA14.RAZON_SOCI END AS [Razón social] ,
    GVA12.COTIZ AS [Cotización] ,
    GVA45.[DESC] as [Num_Obra]],
    SUM(CASE WHEN GVA12.T_Comp <> 'FAC' and GVA15.Tipo_Comp = 'C' then (-1) ELSE (1) END * GVA53.CANTIDAD) AS [Cantidad] ,
    SUM( CASE WHEN GVA12.T_Comp <> 'FAC' and GVA15.Tipo_Comp = 'C' then (-1) ELSE (1) END *      CASE GVA12.Cotiz WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE           CASE 'BIMONCTE'               WHEN 'BIMONCTE' THEN (CASE GVA12.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  ELSE GVA53. IMP_NETO_P  * GVA12.COTIZ END)                WHEN 'BIORIGEN' THEN (CASE GVA12.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  / GVA12.COTIZ ELSE GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  END)                WHEN 'BICOTIZ'  THEN(CASE GVA12.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  / 1 ELSE GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  * GVA12.COTIZ  / 1 END)           END       END ) AS [Total] 
FROM 
    GVA12 (NOLOCK)  
INNER JOIN 
    GVA53 (NOLOCK) ON GVA53.T_COMP = GVA12.T_COMP AND GVA53.N_COMP = GVA12.N_COMP 
 INNER JOIN 
    GVA23 (NOLOCK) ON GVA12.COD_VENDED = GVA23.COD_VENDED
 LEFT JOIN 
    GVA14 (NOLOCK) ON GVA12.COD_CLIENT = GVA14.COD_CLIENT
LEFT JOIN 
    GVA15 ON GVA15.IDENT_COMP = GVA12.T_COMP
LEFT JOIN 
    GVA45 (NOLOCK) ON GVA53.COD_ARTICU = 'NºOBRA' AND
GVA45.N_COMP = GVA53.N_COMP AND GVA45.N_RENGLON = GVA53.N_RENGL_V 
WHERE 
    (GVA53.COD_ARTICU <> 'Art. Ajuste') AND (GVA53.COD_ARTICU <> '')
    AND (GVA53.RENGL_PADR = 0 OR GVA53.INSUMO_KIT_SEPARADO =1)
GROUP BY 
    GVA12.FECHA_EMIS , GVA53.T_Comp , GVA53.N_Comp , GVA12.COD_VENDED , CASE GVA12.COD_VENDED WHEN '**' THEN 'CONTADO' ELSE GVA23.NOMBRE_VEN END , GVA12.COD_CLIENT , CASE GVA12.COD_CLIENT WHEN '000000' THEN 'OCASIONAL' ELSE GVA14.RAZON_SOCI END , GVA12.COTIZ,GVA45.[DESC]
```

My current output:

```
number_invoce     client          Number_Of_Work  Total         
FAC A000500000354 Hospital        NULL              90
FAC A000500000354 Hospital        346300            0.000000
```

My expected output:

```
number_invoce     client          Number_Of_Work    Total         
A000500000354     Hospital        346300            90
```

I have a lot of different tables, most of them are not related to the question, so i will only explain the ones that matter:

GVA53: It have all the lines from an invoice

For example will be

```
   number_invoce COD_ARTICU      AMOUNT N_RENGL_V
   A000500000354 Wall            $50    1
   A000500000354 Roof            $40    2
   A000500000354 number_of_work  $0     3
```

GVA45: It have the description of an article

```
   number_invoce DESC   N_RENGL
   A000500000354        1
   A000500000354        2
   A000500000354 346300 3
```

In resume: I need to get the total from an invoice, I need to sum the items, and I need to get the DESC (description) field from the item number of work, relating n_rengl(number of line) from GV45 to n_rengl_v of GV53 and where COD_ARTIC is equal to number_of_work. Everything is working but I don't get why my data is getting duplicated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Thanks, the query was generated from a tool the contability software have. I removed all the NOLOCK but i still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok one last try :P

As suggested in comments I'm not sure the value of noLock here but as they were not causing the problem you wanted to address I left them in presently.  I don't condone the use however.

The issue is the group by on GVA45.[DESC] is resulting in two values null due to the left joins and an actual value.  Since you only want the values, you need to have the system return the max and eliminate it from the group by.

This may do it...

```
SELECT 
    GVA12.FECHA_EMIS AS [Fecha de emisión] ,
    GVA53.T_Comp AS [Tipo comprobante] ,
    GVA53.N_Comp AS [Nro. comprobante] ,
    GVA12.COD_VENDED AS [Cód. vendedor] ,
    CASE GVA12.COD_VENDED WHEN '**' THEN 'CONTADO' ELSE GVA23.NOMBRE_VEN END AS [Nombre Vendedor] ,
    GVA12.COD_CLIENT AS [Cód. cliente] ,
    CASE GVA12.COD_CLIENT WHEN '000000' THEN 'OCASIONAL' ELSE GVA14.RAZON_SOCI END AS [Razón social] ,
    GVA12.COTIZ AS [Cotización] ,
    max(GVA45.[DESC]) as [Num_Obra]],
    SUM(CASE WHEN GVA12.T_Comp <> 'FAC' and GVA15.Tipo_Comp = 'C' then (-1) ELSE (1) END * GVA53.CANTIDAD) AS [Cantidad] ,
    SUM( CASE WHEN GVA12.T_Comp <> 'FAC' and GVA15.Tipo_Comp = 'C' then (-1) ELSE (1) END *      CASE GVA12.Cotiz WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE           CASE 'BIMONCTE'               WHEN 'BIMONCTE' THEN (CASE GVA12.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  ELSE GVA53. IMP_NETO_P  * GVA12.COTIZ END)                WHEN 'BIORIGEN' THEN (CASE GVA12.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  / GVA12.COTIZ ELSE GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  END)                WHEN 'BICOTIZ'  THEN(CASE GVA12.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  / 1 ELSE GVA53.IMP_NETO_P  * GVA12.COTIZ  / 1 END)           END       END ) AS [Total] 
FROM 
    GVA12 (NOLOCK)  
INNER JOIN 
    GVA53 (NOLOCK) ON GVA53.T_COMP = GVA12.T_COMP AND GVA53.N_COMP = GVA12.N_COMP 
 INNER JOIN 
    GVA23 (NOLOCK) ON GVA12.COD_VENDED = GVA23.COD_VENDED
 LEFT JOIN 
    GVA14 (NOLOCK) ON GVA12.COD_CLIENT = GVA14.COD_CLIENT
LEFT JOIN 
    GVA15 ON GVA15.IDENT_COMP = GVA12.T_COMP
LEFT JOIN 
    GVA45 (NOLOCK) ON GVA53.COD_ARTICU = 'NºOBRA' AND
GVA45.N_COMP = GVA53.N_COMP AND GVA45.N_RENGLON = GVA53.N_RENGL_V 
WHERE 
    (GVA53.COD_ARTICU <> 'Art. Ajuste') AND (GVA53.COD_ARTICU <> '')
    AND (GVA53.RENGL_PADR = 0 OR GVA53.INSUMO_KIT_SEPARADO =1)
GROUP BY 
    GVA12.FECHA_EMIS , GVA53.T_Comp , GVA53.N_Comp , GVA12.COD_VENDED , CASE GVA12.COD_VENDED WHEN '**' THEN 'CONTADO' ELSE GVA23.NOMBRE_VEN END , GVA12.COD_CLIENT , CASE GVA12.COD_CLIENT WHEN '000000' THEN 'OCASIONAL' ELSE GVA14.RAZON_SOCI END , GVA12.COTIZ
```

Comment: Thank you, i can only have one value for DESC in GVA45 related to num_obra. I tried both options, first one is saying  that cannot find the join for GVA53.COD_ARTICU , GVA53.N_COMP 
  ,GVA53.N_RENGL_V corresponding to the LEFT JOING with GVA45. And the second one is showing a sintax error in the group by that is ending with , GVA12.COTIZ) inLine_V (line 27), i tried to fix it but i couldn't

Comment: well the assumption I was making was flawed then.  and neither will work even if I correct the syntax issues.  To solve this issue you need to find which join is causing multiple records in GVA12, GVA53 or GVA15.  One of these joins is likely causing multiple records to exist which is resulting in the sum being artificially inflated.  We need to understand the carnality between the tables and data to address this issue.  Which will likely result in creating the sum before some of the additional joins or aggregating records before a join.Perhaps moving the where clause to the table join instead

Comment: I am sorry, i made a mistake when i wrote the question, i will edit it now, i dont have a problem with the total, my total is fine, just i want to have only one line for the invoice with Num_obra, my current output is a row with total 0 and correct num_obra and second row with correct total(90) and num_obra null

Comment: Does changing the line `GVA45.[Desc] as [Num_obra]` to `Max(GVA45.[DESC]) as [Num_Obra],` and remove `GVA45.[DESC]` from group by solve the problem?  if not we may have to build an additinoal aggregrate.

Comment: Yes! solved. Thank you very much. Sorry for how basic the question was.

Comment: Ok the issue was the group by was causing the added row due to the null value on some records.  As a result when we use max we can get the largest non-null value and then allow the other records to group as needed.  We all make mistakes, learning from them and not making similar ones later is what's important.